# hints for naming methods

Tags: oop, object

We all know that classes/objects should represent things
while methods/messages should represent operations (verbs).
**But how to pick the right verb?**

I've heard one "rule for method naming" is to
imagine some completely different implementations and then
simply pick name that is general for all of them.

EDIT: I also know that methods should be named as closest to domain as possible.
(means after intention not after implementation)

What others do you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to try to name things so that a given line of code would make as much grammatical and syntactic sense as possible, even to a non-programmer.  (One of the reasons why I love lambda so much in my .NET code.  It's like making new words from Latin roots, you just keep chaining things together.)

There's a pretty good article [here](http://fragmental.tw/2010/12/23/how-to-write-a-repository/) on naming classes and methods when building a repository, for example.